# can I automatically rotate the display when steamlink is running without a desktop environment?

Tags: pi-4, retropie

I am running a raspberry pi 4 with a waveshare xpt 2046 screen, which has vertical orientation by default. I am running retropie, and I want to be able to use steamlink on it. the problem is that the X session that steamlink launches in isnt running until steamlink is open, so I cant use any of the xrandr commands to automatically rotate the screen with a bash script. Is there a way I can automatically cause the X session to rotate when steamlink is open?

Thanks.